# How to configure GCP App Engine app.yaml for PrivateBin?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I would like to host PrivateBin from a GCP App Engine, but I don't know how to configure the `app.yaml` file. If somebody has done this before, I would appreciate the help. :)

I have tried two options, but neither of them worked:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

&

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /(.*.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$|htm$|html$|css$|js$|xml$))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$|htm$|html$|css$|js$|xml$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+)
  script: \1

- url: /
  script: index.php
```

Comment: It seems you can deploy it with a container into the GCP. Used the PrivateBin docker container image, works great!

Answer (score 1):

How do you intend to store your data?

https://github.com/PrivateBin/PrivateBin/blob/master/INSTALL.md#using-a-database-instead-of-flat-files

Looks like private bin uses the filesystem by default, which wont work on GAE Standard. You could do that in GAE flex, but the directory where you are reading and writing to would need to be a mounted Google Cloud Storage Bucket or something for the data to be persistent (as well as be available to multiple instances) https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

The better route seems to be to configure privatebin to use a SQL db, which would be Google Cloud SQL:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/

https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-sql-with-mysql